# How to create Openlayer Feature previews in a dropdown menu?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to create a menu which shows the list of openLayer Features saved in database with a preview option.each preview can have multiple Openlayer features(grouped features).I couldn't find a way to place the features in a small scale area.
Do you have any ideas for achieving this?
I am using Openlayers4.

When I click the drop down options, the features will be placed over the map based on the GeoJSON saved in db.
I tried to put the items in a small canvas which is not working

Answer (score 2):

The ol.control.Legend of [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) has a getStyleImage method to get a canvas legend of the feature.
Look at this example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/legend/map.control.legend.html

Comment: Thank you, Can I use it to create exact images of shapes drawn over the map and place it in a separate html canvas?

Comment: @ViglinoJeanMarc Could you please check the above comment?

Comment: Look at ol/render/toContext https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render.html to draw features in your own canvas.